# How can I show an AlertDialog after click on share

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have an app that uploads images from a gallery . 
After i click on share and pick my app , it launches my app and the upload begins.But i want to launch the upload without being redirected to my app , but through an alert dialog directly appearing after clicking on share.
How can i do this?
Thank you for your answers

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".App">

    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: here's the code @Roy

Answer (score 0):

If your application is used for just sharing you can create activity and apply Dialog theme. In Manifest use the following theme

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

Or if your app does some thing else also then create share activity and use intent filter with that activity and apply same above method with that also.

Comment: Ok so whoever has done. if you can't help don't stop others. and if you don't know what's wrong don't be over smart